# Proper form of HTTPS request

Tags: c#, httprequest, webclient

I need to send POST request and recieve access token.
Http request should look like this:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.quizlet.com
Authorization: Basic c3ZWRUhNZVA0aDp3eS4yUXA0ZXNFY0xQUFl2WkRFTGpn
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

grant_type=authorization_code&code=GENERATED_CODE
```

I don't know, how to send "grant_type" and "code" in my request, because (according to Fiddler, where I have tested it) they should be in Request body.

Code I have looks like this:

```
            client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +       "MY_SECRET_CODE";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "api.quizlet.com";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "UTF-8";
            client.UploadStringCompleted += ClientOnUploadStringCompleted;
            client.UploadStringAsync(tokenUrl, "POST",string.Format("grant_type={0}&code={1}",
                                                   HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("authorization_code"),HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code)));
```

Btw, this code runs on WP7 and I have been messing with this single request for almost 2 days and those values, that I provide in request, are 100% right, because I tried to paste sample request in Fiddler and recieved proper token.

EDIT:
I forgot redirect_uri parameter in the data, which I tried to upload, so it didn't work...Proper data string should look like this:

```
 string.Format("grant_type={0}&code={1}&redirect_uri={2}",
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("authorization_code"),HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code),    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("http://someurl.com"))
```

Comment: Side note: It may be easier to write regular WinForm/console code first and debug it (as you can intercept traffic using Fiddler much easier on Windows than of phone) and only than port code to the phone.

Comment: The code works for me.  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Thank everybody for help, I changed AcceptCharset header to proper form and debugged it in WinForms. Lastly I realized, that I forgot redirect_uri parameter in data, because that Host header replaced it.
Everything works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At least one issue seems to be that the expected character set for the target server should be set in the ContentType header and not the AcceptCharset:

```
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "api.quizlet.com";
            //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "UTF-8";
```